# Symfony2, include file error

Tags: php, symfony

I got a weird problem. I've simply two php pages: `Index.html.php` and `Header.php` containing just HTML codes running on a `Symfony2` project. The Index page contains a very normal include: `include "Header.php"`. The problem is that, when I load the Index for the first time the page renders normally, everything is in place, but the second time I refresh the page, I got this error:

```
at ErrorHandler ->handle ('2', 'include(Header.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory', '', '30', array('template' => object(FileStorage), 'parameters' => array('app' => object(GlobalVariables)), '__template__' => object(FileStorage), 'this' => object(PhpEngine), 'app' => object(GlobalVariables), 'view' => object(PhpEngine)))
in wamp\www\**\src\**\**Bundle/Resources/views/Default/Index.html.php at line 30 

at include ()
in wamp\www\**\src\**\**Bundle/Resources/views/Default/Index.html.php at line 30 
at require ('')
in C:\wamp\www\**\app\cache\dev\classes.php at line 2490 

at PhpEngine ->evaluate (object(FileStorage), array('app' => object(GlobalVariables)))
in C:\wamp\www\**\app\cache\dev\classes.php at line 2440  

at PhpEngine ->render ('**Bundle:Default:Index.html.php', array())
in C:\wamp\www\**\app\cache\dev\classes.php at line 2778 

at PhpEngine ->renderResponse ('**Bundle:Default:Index.html.php', array(), null)
in C:\wamp\www\**\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\DelegatingEngine.php at line 87

at DelegatingEngine ->renderResponse ('**Bundle:Default:Index.html.php', array(), null)
in C:\wamp\www\**\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php at line 99 

at Controller ->render ('**Bundle:Default:Index.html.php')
in C:\wamp\www\**\src\**\**Bundle\Controller\DefaultController.php at line 15

at DefaultController ->indexAction ()

at call_user_func_array (array(object(DefaultController), 'indexAction'), array())
in C:\wamp\www\**\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 1421

at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in C:\wamp\www\**\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 1385 

at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in C:\wamp\www\**\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 1561

at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in C:\wamp\www\**\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 612

at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in C:/wamp/www/**/web/app_dev.php at line 28
```

I checked the file, it really exists in the same directory as the Index file. I checked the letter cases either. Notice that the project was made out of Symfony and every things went well, but when I created a Sf2.1 project and put the files on I got this problem. I'm using Windows7 and WampServer 2.1. I wish I've provided enough info about the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first request php renders fresh template, on the next requests php renders templates from cache. since Header.php is not cached php throws file not found exception.

Use render function instead of include. Check this [Including other Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/PHP.html#including-other-templates) or you can just pass full path to include()

Comment: Actually, I used to call include `Header.php` the same way in previous projects but I didn't get this problem, but the difference is that I was using Symfony2.0 and this tims I'm using Symfony2.1. Is that new in the latest version or what?

Comment: I just checked it in 2.1.2 version and it works fine (in dev and prod enviroments). Update vendors to recent version and/or try to pass full path to Header.php

Comment: It has been a while since I have the problem. I was busy on something else. BTW, really very strange. I don't have to update the vendors because I downloaded the whole version. I tried writing the whole path, but I got the same error. **Why the included files aren't cached?!**

Comment: Well, rendering the template works now, but still need an explanation for that. Include files still work using `include "";` perfectly in Symfony 2.0.0.